# Windows Phone 8 Wont load XAP files

Tags: windows-phone-8

Im trying to deploy XAP files to my Lumia 620. They work if i download them from the store but when i try and load another XAP from somewhere else, e.g. TimeMe or from Windows Phone Hub, the phone fails to show them. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone 8 OS architecture doesn't allow installation of non store applications, to support this they have restricted the loading of XAP files from other download sources.
In some countries Window Phone store comes with a option for installation from SD Card option, under this option you will be able to view XAP files on your storage media of phone, if you select that XAP file the store application will check for that application in the Windows Store and if it is a free app it will get installed otherwise it will ask to buy for a license of the app to install it.

The Windows Phone hub is for enterprise environment, where a company distributes its LOB apps to its employees, if you are able to access company hub app than you must be able to download and install the app. Even in this case the process is automated as in case of Windows Store and nowhere you will manually unpack the final XAP file.

Comment: How do i test homebrew apps if you can only get apps from the store? My phone is dev unlocked by the way

Comment: You can use App Deployment Tool or Window Phone Power Tools

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone will not let you install XAP files that are not certified in the WP Store. The only way you'll be able to install XAP files yourself is to either:

1. Download and install a WP Store signed XAP file. You can do this by going to an app's page on your computer, downloading the XAP file, transferring it to your SD card, and installing it through the Store app.
2. Download and install a unsigned XAP file that hasn't been through the WP Store yet. You can install these XAP files on a developer unlocked phone using the `Application Deployment` program included with the WP8 SDK.

The app `TimeMe` that you included as an example is an unsigned XAP file. You can "sideload" this app through the `Application Deployment` program.